# Unable to retrieve logged in Outlook accounts in .NET MAUI Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, outlook, maui

I'm making an app which requires me to retrieve logged in Outlook accounts from my Android device. The code for retrieving works, as I've been able to get both Google and Whatsapp accounts, but Outlook accounts are missing (even though they are logged in on the device). What am I doing wrong?

The code:

```
public partial class LandingPage : ContentPage
{
    public LandingPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

    #if ANDROID

        PermissionStatus status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.ContactsRead>();

        var emails = new List<string>();

        var manager = `Android.Accounts.AccountManager.Get(Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.Platform.CurrentActivity);`
        var accounts = manager.GetAccounts();

        var intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null, null,
        new String[] { "com.google", "com.google.android.legacyimap" },
        false, null, null, null, null);

        foreach (var acc in accounts)
        {
            emails.Add(acc.Name);
        }

    #endif
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not know about outlook, but if you want want all accounts you can just call the function with "null" set for every parameter. (I think you are filtering them out now)

Comment: Can you make sure the outlook app supports account detecting?